# How compare the orientation from one node to another

Tags: javafx, orientation

I am trying to get a  node's point to connect to another node's point depending on the orientation of the first node. The problem is, I am having trouble thinking of the way a node call tell whether it is left, right , north or south given its X and Y positions and Width and Height.
Here is an image of the problem: [image]

I have tried comparing the X and Y values, for example, if (child.Y > parent.Y) -> snap to southPoint, but it is too vague and will snap to north or south if it is placed right or left. Any idea on more specific conditions I can use to get the correct orientation? Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to find the orientation of the two nodes or just the position of the nodes?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it is confusing. I want defaultClass' line to connect to the right point of defaultInterface. The  first condition I have here is that if defaultClass' Y is less than defaultInterface's Y, then it will snap to the north point. That will always be the case if defaultClass' Y is higher although it is to the right of defaultInterface.

Comment: Whether it is at the right can be calculated by knowing the X co-ordinate of the node. So the most simple solution is to know the `layoutX` / `layoutY` of both the Pane and compare them.

Comment: Yes, I know to use layoutX and layoutY but I am having trouble coming up with the exact conditions using those to get the correct direction

Comment: Have you written any code ? Where exactly does the problem lie? Can you come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by defining anchor points on your box:

```
public class UMLClassBox {
  private Point2D north;
  private Point2D east;
  private Point2D south;
  private Point2D west;
  public List<Point> getAnchorPoints() {
    ...
  }
}
```

As a second step you then can have a method to find the two nodes that are closest:

```
public Point2D[] findClosestNodes(UMLClassBox box1, UMLClassBox box2) {
  Point2D[] closest = new Point2D[2];
  double shortestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
  for (Point2D anchorBox1 : box1.getAnchorPoints()) {
    for (Point2D anchorBox2 : box2.getAnchorPoints()) {
      double distance = anchorBox1.distance(anchorBox2);
      if (distance < shortestDistance) {
        shortestDistance = distance;
        closest[0] = anchorBox1;
        closest[1] = anchorBox2;
      }
    }
  }
  return closest;
}
```

While there is a chance that two anchor points pairs have the same distance, this should not matter in this case because either of those would be equally valid.